# Vanishing Ricci Tensor with Torsion

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

Under what condition for the Torsion tensor does the Ricci Tensor vanish?
I know that the Riemann Tensor is defined through:
$$-R_{abc}^dV_d=\left(\nabla_a \nabla_b -\nabla_b \nabla_a \right)V_c-T^d_{ab}\nabla_dV_c$$
The Ricci Tensor is defined as:
$$R_{ab}=R_{acb}^c$$
But I dont know how to find a condition on the Torsion tensor such that the Ricci Tensor vanishes.

Comment: Could one just set the right hand side equal to 0?

Comment: There is no sufficient condition: Even if the torsion is zero, it is possible both for the Ricci tensor to vanish and for it not to vanish, as there are both Ricci-flat and non--Ricci-flat Riemannian metrics.